# Unable to boot macOS on mac mini after failed Ubuntu Server installation

Tags: macos, partition, apfs

I thought I could handle installing Ubuntu Server on my mac mini without a backup & was promptly rewarded for my arrogance: the installer failed and upon rebooting my normal macOS startup disk was gone.

Details: 2018 Mac Mini, 256 GB of storage. I had previously installed Ubuntu on a partition but later removed it. However, I do not believe I was fully able to remove the boot manager I installed alongside this (rEFInd). I created a new 25gb partition in macOS to prepare for the Ubuntu Server installation. I've been using a bootable Ubuntu USB to access hexdump and some other utilities. I ended up reinstalling rEFInd while in Ubuntu to see if that would help anything. I have minimal relevant experience or knowledge, so it's entirely possible that my attempts to fix the situation have made things worse.

Based on previous answers here, I looked at the GPT and found it appeared to be incorrect. Unfortunately, I did not capture the original GPT before I started messing with it. After several attempts, I believe I have now correctly calculated that the APFS partition starts at sector 899112 and is 55099017 sectors long.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo dd if=/dev/nvme0n1 bs=4096 count=1 skip=899112 |hexdump -Cv
00000000  23 c7 3f 85 e6 48 45 67  01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |#.?..HEg........|
00000010  87 81 4a 00 00 00 00 00  01 00 00 80 00 00 00 00  |..J.............|
00000020  4e 58 53 42 00 10 00 00  89 be 48 03 00 00 00 00  |NXSB......H.....|
```

I corrected this in Recovery Mode, but verifyVolume still does not work. Instead it returns warnings about  "checkpoint [number] fsck_obj_phys failed" and errors "no valid checkpoint found", "-60716: Storage system verify or repair failed", "Underlying error 8".

Disk Utility in recovery mode currently shows AppleAPFSMedia (225.69 GB) and APFS Physical Store disk0s2 (also 225.69 GB, not mounted).

diskutil list currently returns

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical)
#:  TYPE            NAME            SIZE                IDENTIFIER
0:  GUID_partition_scheme           *251.0GB            disk0
1:  EFI             EFI             314.6MB             disk0s1
    (free space)                    3.4 GB              -           -
2:  Apple AAPFS     Container disk1 18.9GB              disk0s2
    (free space)                    21.6 GB             - 

/dev/disk1 (synthesized)
#:  TYPE                    NAME        SIZE        IDENTIFIER
0:  APFS Container Scheme   -           +ERROR              disk1
        Physical Store     disk0s2
```

gpt -r show disk0:

```
start   size        index       contents
0           1               PMBR
1           1               Pri GPT header
2           4               Pri GPT table
6           76800    1        GPT part C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
76806       822306      
899112      55099017 2    GPT part 7C3457EF-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
55998129    5281210         
61279339        4               Sec GPT table
61279343    1              Sec GPT header
```

gpt -r show disk1

```
start       size        index       contents
0       55099017
```

diskutil list apfs returns errors -69808 and -69620.

Various utilities I've tried in Ubuntu seem to indicate duplication.

Fdisk appears to have the APFS partition twice, though the second time in an unknown format.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 233.76 GiB, 251000193024 bytes, 61279344 sectors
Disk model: APPLE SSD AP0256M                       
Units: sectors of 1 * 4096 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 86E66793-A908-424A-9B89-1427CBD54007

Device          Start      End  Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1      6    76805    76800   300M EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 899112 55998128 55099017 210.2G Apple APFS
/dev/nvme0n1p3 899112 55998128 55099017 210.2G unknown
```

TestDisk indicates that there is a FAT32 partition in the middle of where the APFS partition is supposed to be.

```
FAT32 at 26941/24/1
FAT: cluster=2(0x2), pos=55178948
     MS Data                 55175936   61279231    6103296 [U]
     FAT32, blocksize=16384, 24 GB / 23 GiB
```

Hexdump seems to confirm this.

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo dd if=/dev/nvme0n1 bs=4096 count=1 skip=55175936 |hexdump -Cv
00000000  eb 58 90 42 53 44 20 20  34 2e 34 00 10 04 20 00  |.X.BSD  4.4... .|
00000010  02 00 00 00 00 f8 00 00  20 00 ff 00 00 eb 49 03  |........ .....I.|
00000020  00 21 5d 00 d2 05 00 00  00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00  |.!].............|
00000030  01 00 06 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  80 00 29 ff 09 6d a0 55  20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20  |..)..m.U        |
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
4096 bytes (4.1 kB, 4.0 KiB) copied, 0.000382055 s, 10.7 MB/s
00000050  20 20 46 41 54 33 32 20  20 20 fa 31 c0 8e d0 bc  |  FAT32   .1....|
00000060  00 7c fb 8e d8 e8 00 00  5e 83 c6 19 bb 07 00 fc  |.|......^.......|
00000070  ac 84 c0 74 06 b4 0e cd  10 eb f5 30 e4 cd 16 cd  |...t.......0....|
00000080  19 0d 0a 4e 6f 6e 2d 73  79 73 74 65 6d 20 64 69  |...Non-system di|
00000090  73 6b 0d 0a 50 72 65 73  73 20 61 6e 79 20 6b 65  |sk..Press any ke|
000000a0  79 20 74 6f 20 72 65 62  6f 6f 74 0d 0a 00 00 00  |y to reboot.....|
```

TestDisk also seems to indicate that the EFI partition as well as the FAT32 partition are doubled.

```
FAT32 at 26941/24/7
FAT: Directory entry is marked as free.
FAT: cluster=2(0x2), pos=55178954
     MS Data                 55175942   61279237    6103296 [U]
     FAT32, blocksize=16384, 24 GB / 23 GiB

Results
     EFI System                     6      76805      76800 [EFI System Partition] [EFI]
     FAT32, blocksize=4096, 314 MB / 300 MiB
     EFI System                    12      76811      76800 [EFI System Partition] [EFI]
     FAT32, blocksize=4096, 314 MB / 300 MiB
     MS Data                 55175936   61279231    6103296 [U]
     FAT32, blocksize=16384, 24 GB / 23 GiB
     MS Data                 55175942   61279237    6103296 [U]
     FAT32, blocksize=16384, 24 GB / 23 GiB
```

Hexdumps for the two indicated EFI partition locations were identical.

```
00000000  eb 58 90 42 53 44 20 20  34 2e 34 00 10 01 20 00  |.X.BSD  4.4... .|
00000010  02 00 00 00 00 f0 00 00  20 00 10 00 00 00 00 00  |........ .......|
00000020  00 2c 01 00 4b 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00  |.,..K...........|
00000030  01 00 06 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
00000040  00 00 29 ed 17 66 5f 45  46 49 20 20 20 20 20 20  |..)..f_EFI      |
00000050  20 20 46 41 54 33 32 20  20 20 fa 31 c0 8e d0 bc  |  FAT32   .1....|
00000060  00 7c fb 8e d8 e8 00 00  5e 83 c6 19 bb 07 00 fc  |.|......^.......|
00000070  ac 84 c0 74 06 b4 0e cd  10 eb f5 30 e4 cd 16 cd  |...t.......0....|
00000080  19 0d 0a 4e 6f 6e 2d 73  79 73 74 65 6d 20 64 69  |...Non-system di|
00000090  73 6b 0d 0a 50 72 65 73  73 20 61 6e 79 20 6b 65  |sk..Press any ke|
000000a0  79 20 74 6f 20 72 65 62  6f 6f 74 0d 0a 00 00 00  |y to reboot.....|
```

Hexdumps for the two indicated FAT32 partitions were also identical.

I would like to perform data recovery to make a backup copy now. What options exist?

**Edit**

As suggested by bmike, I installed macOS on an external drive and booted from there. Unfortunately, the recovery software was not able to recover any of my files.

Comment: Excellent details. Can we presume you wish to delay changes and not erase / install this Mac? If so, editing a specific question with clearly defined results will help us help you.

Comment: @bmike Yes, there's some files on there that I would really like to preserve if at all possible. Thank you!

Comment: Data recovery software exists for when you don’t have a bootable OS. Do you have a spare external drive so you could install elsewhere and run that recovery and keep this disk unchanged? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/55956/recovering-an-accidentally-deleted-folder-in-osx-no-time-machine-or-backup-av

Comment: @bmike Just to confirm, you mean install macOS to an external drive -> plug that into the mac mini -> select the external disk as the boot disk -> install the recovery software there? This hasn't worked & I can edit to add more detail but wanted to check I hadn't misunderstood.

Comment: Yes, macOS installer can install onto USB, FireWire and Thunderbolt external drives, leaving the unbootable internal drive alone. You don’t have to fix this device to move forward.

Comment: @bmike managed to boot from the external drive today but Data Rescue did not recover any of my files

Comment: Oh no, that is awful. If you can wait a week. Maybe one of the disk partition wizard has a thought. Not sure how much value your files are… great work trying the best chance for recovery.